# How to filter by nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

I got the following code:

```
this.setState({
   data: data.filter(entry =>
      entry.A.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
      || entry.B.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
      || entry.C.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
   )
})
```

Which works and filters the strings correctly but I also have 2 more properties `D` and `E` which are arrays of strings

```
      || entry.D.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
      || entry.E.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) > -1
```

and when I add the last 2 properties I get the following error:

```
TypeError: entry.D.toLowerCase is not a function
```

How do I filter by nested arrays in this case?

Comment: Do `console.log(entry.D)`. It is probably not a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform the arrays of strings to their lowercase equivalent (which can be done with `.map`), and then you can check whether `some` of their containing strings `includes` the `event.target.value`:

```
  || entry.D.some(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
  || entry.E.some(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))
```

Or, to be less repetitive:

```
const lowerValue = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
this.setState({
   data: data.filter(entry =>
      entry.A.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue)
      || entry.B.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue)
      || entry.C.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue)
      || entry.D.some(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue))
      || entry.E.some(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(lowerValue))
   )
})
```

Or, to be even less repetitive:

```
const lowerValue = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
const entries = [entry.A, entry.B, entry.C, ...entry.D, ...entry.E]
  .map(str => str.toLowerCase());
this.setState({
   data: data.filter(entry => entries.some(str => str.includes(lowerValue)))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the value to a string and collect all properties in an array.

```
var string = event.target.value.toLowerCase(),
    keys = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

this.setState({
    data: data.filter(entry => keys.some(k => entry[k]
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(string)
    ))
});
```